# What could cause text segment in a static binary not to be sharable?

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to track down unwanted dirty pages in small binaries on Linux x86. The whole binary is less than a 4k page (it's compiled without glibc). On my laptop running a 2.6.32 kernel, `.text` shows up in `/proc/$pid/smaps` as `Private_Clean: 4` and `Private_Dirty: 0`, as expected, but on my server with 2.6.36, `.text` is `Private_Dirty: 4`. Any idea what could cause this? As far as I know, no address layout randomization or similar is in effect (I've disabled all related settings that I know of). Any idea what could be dirtying the program's `.text`?

**Edit:**

```
$ strace ~/em2
execve("/home/R/em2", ["/home/R/em2"], [/* 28 vars */]) = 0
nanosleep({100000, 0}, ^C <unfinished ...>
```

And..... now `smaps` is showing `.text` as `Private_Clean: 4`. It's very strange, because I actually have 2 different binaries compiled on different machines that were **both** showing the inexplicable dirty page when run on my server, and now they're both clean. Sorry for wasting everybody's time. If the issue doesn't come back, I'll close/delete this question or whatever is appropriate since I can no longer reproduce it.

Comment: Please add the excerpt of `smaps` (all entries that show your program's file name - of which there are usually at least three) to your post.

Comment: Could you please also post the output of `ldd {yourapp}` and `strace {yourapp} 2>&1|grep "^mmap\|mprotect"` for your application.

Comment: By the way. Must have reading about **How To Write Shared Libraries by Ulrich Drepper** (http://people.redhat.com/drepper/dsohowto.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved: Apparently Linux has a "feature" (I would call it a bug) where the page shows up as `Private_Dirty` if the binary file has not yet been flushed out to disk after creating it. This is why the problem mysteriously went away after a while.